# How to Query the EmailMessage Origin Routing Address of a Case from Email-to-Case

Tags: email2case, servicecloud, emailmessage, case-object

We need to know which email routing address the case (created from Email-to-Case) was created.

Here's a sample scenario that we have:

Currently, we have 2 mailboxes forwarding to Salesforce. (Let's say mailbox A and mailbox B)

1. User sends a single email addressed to both mailboxes A and B.
2. Two cases will be created: Case A and Case B.

We need to know which mailbox Case A did come from. We know Case object has link to Email Message object but is there a maybe a link from EmailMessage object to EmailServicesAddress? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to find out case created from which email-to-case?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18299/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-case-created-from-which-email-to-case)

Comment: @cropredy sorry no, it's the other way around, we need to know which email routing address did the case come from.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is use a different origin per email services address. Your before save flow/apex trigger can copy that to a custom field and then replace Case.Origin with `Email`

Comment: Did you ever figure a way out to do this?